# Bash Shell Scripts: Although apt-get update Failed, The Exit Status Is 0, Writing Automatic Update Scripts With Utilizing Exit Staus

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts, updates

I am trying to write automatic update and upgrade script.

I want to utilize command execution's exit status,

but even if the apt-get update command fails, it returns exit status 0.

So my script can not achieve the purpose.

QUESTIONS===========

Why does apt-get update return 0, I want to get other numbers rather than 0 when the command fails though?

And to make my script achieve the purpuse, how could I modify it?

=====================

Thank you for your reading!

Here is the update part of my script;

```
#!/bin/bash -x 

### Variables
count=
command_result=""

### Main

echo "$(LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date)" >> log_update

until [ "$count" = "10" ] || [ "$command_result" = "done" ]; do

    sudo apt-get update

    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
        echo "Update succeeds." >> ~/log_update
        command_result="done"
    fi

    count=$((count + 1)) 

done

if [ "$command" != "done" ]; then
    echo "Time Out: Update FAILED! Solve Problem." >> log_update
fi
```

Comment: I have a similar script. If you want to save the last exit status code of the `sudo apt-get update` command, you have to save it as a variable. For instance, add a line right after `sudo apt-get update` with `last_exit=$?` and do the next check with `if [[ $last_exit -eq 0 ]]; then`. Is this what you want? Else please elaborate.

Comment: And maybe to elaborate on what user535733 says: Have you ever experienced that a `sudo apt-get update` failed? Do you loose internet connection, or what's up, when does it fail?

Comment: @user535733 Hello! After adding a PPA, I have noticed some error occurs. So I want to implement any check function whether apt-get update succeeded or not on the script.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you for your comment! Although I have modified as you advised, the value of the variable is 0, even if I turn off the wifi conection. Is this situation the success for the command itself?

Comment: Maybe `apt-get update` returns an exit code of 0, even if it does not have internet connection - I honestly don't know.

Comment: @ArturMeinild If you would not mind, I want to know any good way for my purpose. Although you said you have a similar script, what is it like?

Comment: My script does not engage in a loop. I just run the command and save the exit code. When the script is done, it tells me how many commands succeeded and how many failed. And I have never experienced that `apt-get update` failed.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding: Error Code 0 means that apt completed it's run in an expected manner. It means no *internal* errors, regardless of how many *source or package* errors that it encountered. Source errors and package errors are for the human to fix, not apt.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you! Your comment tells me what I have misunderstood. Although, for me, they seem to have failed , It is executed as expectated. Now , I got it!

Comment: @ArturMeinild Hello! Now I have known I had misunderstood exit status 0 and apt-get usually does not fail so . I see! I appriciate your communicating with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why `apt` or `apt-get` returns 0, even when you encounter an error, you should first know that these commands are also a program which was developed by some programmer. Hence the values returned to the terminal are also decided by the developer of the program.

The only case when I have seen `apt` not work is when it is executed without `sudo`
Here is a snippet when apt is executed without superuser privilege :

```
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
100
```

As you can see that the exit code is not 0. Hence we can conclude that command or program was not executed.
Let's take another case, when there is no internet connection :

```
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                   
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                     
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                     
  Could not resolve 'download.sublimetext.com'
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'download.sublimetext.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
0
```

As you see the exit code is 0 even though we encountered an error. The reason for this is that the program or command did execute successfully. However it was unable to update the package lists for upgrades of packages that need upgrading.

The only explanation for this is that the developer of `apt` command didn't consider the failed to update the package list as an error to stop the command itself and return an error exit status code. Instead the command provides warnings after execution.

**To give a better understanding I am going to take an example of C program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc==2) 
        printf("Welcome Master %s\n", argv[1]);
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman
Usage : ./batman <name>
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
1
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman Bruce
Welcome Master Bruce
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see there are 2 different exit status code, because as a programmer I considered that command executed with no argument is an error and should be terminated with exit code "1". ( I could choose any value ). And if command executed successfully I returned "0" as exit status code which signifies that no error was encountered.

**Lets take another example :**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc==2) 
        printf("Welcome Master %s\n", argv[1]);
    else
        printf("ERROR!!\nUsage : %s <name>\n", argv[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman_error 
ERROR!!
Usage : ./batman_error <name>
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
0
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman_error Bruce
Welcome Master Bruce
mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ echo $?
0
```

Again the same program but this time the programmer ( i.e. me ) did not consider to terminate the program with a different exit status code. Hence even though terminal prints an output of Error the exit status code is "0".

### Conclusion

It is up to the developer of the program which value to return ( i.e. exit status code ) depending upon the situation.
I hope this clears the concept of exit status code.

### Suggestion on your bash script

I saw that you are using a loop which will try to execute `apt update` command 10 times if it was not executed successfully. To be honest if it didn't work the first time it won't work the next 9 times as well. Hence creating a loop is just pointless.

Now if you want to check for an error use nested if-else conditions. You can check for status code on first level and to check for error with execution of `apt` on second level (i.e. with exit code "0" ) you can use something like :

```
sudo apt update | grep "Err"
```

if `grep` was able to fetch a line then store that as an error in your log file, else update was successful.

Comment: Hello! Reading your several advices, I have understood the behavior of a program is decided by their programmer. Although man pages has parts about exit codes, they are also up to programmers, which I got! I will try to use `grep "Err"`. Anyway only one part, I could not understand. Could I ask about it? It is the line next; "Now if you want to check for an error use nested if-else conditions."
Although I am not native English speaker, "nested if-else conditions" is also means like `grep "Err"`? Can I use it too?

Comment: @CaptainCookie nested if-else means using a if condition inside another if condition. So what I meant by that was you can use your exit status code for your first if condition. If the status code is "0" you can check whether "apt" generated any Error using `grep "Err"` with the help of another if condition. Or you could use `grep "Err"` from start as well, it's totally up to you. If you don't understand anything feel free to ask.

Comment: I found a post similar to yours, feel free to read it : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/apt-get-update-exit-status. might also help you in your script

Comment: If you would not mind, I would like to watch the two-phased approach script. Although such lines came to mind, `sudo apt-get update &>> log_file; if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then grep "Err" log_file fi`, this is just one usage of `if`. And thank you for your providing additional information page link. I will check.

Comment: @CaptainCookie I wrote a pseudo code here, https://pastebin.com/4KjFbCWe. Read it and if you don't understand anything ask here.

Comment: Thanks to your sample, I could make a new version script like here,https://pastebin.com/uCMxuPGb . I will apply this structure to the first task script, executed firstly after the system-boot. Since I saw your C code sample, C programming learning is also advancing. Thank you!

Comment: As the page you provided as a link says W: or E: is included in output if any anomaly occurs, so I have added them to grep's search patterns! The page was also useful.

Comment: @CaptainCookie I am glad I was able to help you understand something better ;)